# Kendo Grid edit popup - Set default TextBox text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to set a default value in **Kendo Grid edit popup**. It's not showing. I tried setting the value with Jquery and model default value also but nothing works.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CountryCode, new { style="width:25px",@value="+94" })
```

Comment: instead giving textbox value this way just put value "+94" in  CountryCode property ,,,

Comment: just remove @value from here and return its value from controller and then check...@chamara..

Comment: @chamara..problem still not solved..??

Comment: @Exception Unfortunately no. still looking for a solution. did you check your answer with the kendo grid popup?

Comment: @chamara...no..i have never used kendo...

Comment: Can you post the code for your grid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { style = "width:25px", @Value = "+94" })
```

Letter `V` should be in upper-case in `@Value = "+94"` .

Comment: @Exception : Yes, normally it should work with `V`. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @chamara: Are you talking about http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-popup ?

Comment: yes. With relevant to the demo. My scenario is like passing a default value to "Product Name"

Comment: Did you try creating an editor-template ? http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates

Answer (score 0):

Instead giving `@Html.TextBoxFor` value with `@value="+94"` as shown in your question  just put

value "+94" in `CountryCode` property from `controller` side,this problem you are getting because

you are using `strongly typed TextBox` here.

Comment: thank you for the answer but it's not clear what you are saying. Could you please provide some sample code

Comment: @chamara..i m saying that when your request is coming to controller just from where you are returning view() there put countrycode property with value "+94"

Answer (score 0):

@chamara have you tried using **.DefaultValue()** in your grid ? This works for me.

Like this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{

    columns.Bound(p => p.UserName);

})
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Add"))
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("template"))
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(f => f.UserName).DefaultValue("+94");
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action(" ", " "))
        .Create(update => update.Action(" ", " "))
        .Update(update => update.Action(" ", " "))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action(" ", " "))
))
```

The defaultValue should be visible in your pop up.

Answer (score 0):

The DefaultValue works only for static default values. But what to do if one likes to have dynamic default values, e.g. when the user selects a value from a DropDownList. I have no idea so far.